# ColorBox (jquery plug in) my textbox values are empty after postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery, colorbox

I'm having trouble getting the values from text box when using ColorBox http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

I have a form that opens a ColorBox modal dialog.In the modal i have a asp.net textbox and a button when i click the button i'm getting the postback but the value of the textbox is always empty.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".example8").colorbox({ width: "50%", inline: true, href: "#inline_example1" });
        });
    </script>
```

....

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <a href="content/ohoopee1.jpg" rel="example8" title="abc">Click here</a></p> <a class='example8'
        href="#">Inline HTML</a></p>
    <!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls -->
    <div style='display: none'>
        <div id='inline_example1' style='padding: 10px; background: #fff;'>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton><asp:TextBox
                ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following code to the method call:

```
$("#colorbox").appendTo('form');
```

So your code will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".example8").colorbox({ width: "50%", inline: true, href: "#inline_example1" });
        $("#colorbox").appendTo('form');
    });
</script>
```

At least that's what worked for me! 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for you reply!

I doesn't seems to work, but maybe because i don't have any element named colorbox.
what is colorbox in your box? 
if you can send me your example it would be very appreciated.

Thanks, Pini.

Comment: As Jack states in teh comments of this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424638/asp-net-form-fields-not-posting-from-colorbox), you need to apply the append to the overlay as well as the post. `$('#cboxOverlay, #colorbox').appendTo('form');`. It worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because the Colorbox's content is created outside form tag.
To resolve the problem edit the colorbox.cs and edit the method that create the modal.
If you prefer, you can download the file that I changed and fix the problem.
http://www.coyote.inf.br/jquery.colorbox.js