# ASP.NET Form Fields Not POSTing from colorbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I've got a form that is displayed inside a jQuery colorbox.  When the form is submitted, the fields within that form are not being posted back to the page.  I modified the javascript to store the form fields into hidden fields on a submit and those DO post back.  The problem is, since this is a login box, I really don't want to move the password around like that.  The main form content is inside an update panel.  Here is the code for my master page:

```
<form id="myform" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" method="post">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ecommerceManager" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EnableViewState="False" EnablePageMethods="True">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery.colorbox.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/eCommerce.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <div style="width: 940px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div align="left">
            TOP OF THE PAGE
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="bodyContent" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            BOTTOM OF THE PAGE
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(closeLoading);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(loadData);
    </script>
    </form>
```

Here is some of the code from my main default page that uses the master page:

```
<asp:Content ID="mainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" runat="server">


    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ecommerceUpdate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlEcomMain" runat="server" CssClass="ecom_main" ClientIDMode="Static">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="statusField" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="False" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUsername" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="False" />


                <div class="add_product">
                    <div class="add_product_menu text_12_bold">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgAddProducts" ImageUrl="~/images/ecom_icon_add_2.gif" CssClass="std_btn" AlternateText="Add Products" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />Add Additional Products:<br /><br />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="newproduct" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                            onchange="addProduct()">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </asp:Panel>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <!--- HERE IS THE COLORBOX POPUP CONTENT --->
            <div style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                <div id="inline_login">
                    <p><strong>User Login Details Go Here</strong></p>

                    User Name: <asp:TextBox ID="loginName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EnableViewState="False" ViewStateMode="Disabled" /><br />
                    Password: <asp:TextBox ID="loginPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" ClientIDMode="Static" /><br />
                    <input type="button" name="loginBtn" id="loginbtn" value="Login" onclick="javascript:validateLogin()" />



                </div>
            </div>

            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Label ID="xmlContent" runat="server" />
       </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>
```

The new product field properly posts, but the username and password doesn't UNLESS I copy it to the hidden fields before a post.  I'm guessing maybe it's a conflict with the update panel?  I was originally trying to get a Login Control working in the Update Panel but read in the forums that there is a known problem with this.

Any insight on this would very tremendously be appreciated.  I'm using firebug and can confirm that the fields simply aren't in the post which is why ASP isn't finding them.

Comment: I had this issue as well. I found that the author of ColorBox addressed it directly on his site: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq#faq-asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, despite being inside the form, the colorbox actually moves the content outside the form.  I was able to resolve this by adding this line of code to my JavaScript submit function:

```
jQuery('#inline_login').appendTo('form');
```

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: You could have also moved colorbox inside of the form:

$('#colorbox').appendTo('form');

This is a problem because you aren't loading the entire form element into colorbox, just the form fields.  This causes your form to break because colorbox's markup exists outside of the form element.

Comment: @Jack, I added this line of code on my submit function. It works well for the first post, but when I went back to open a colorbox for another add/edit the overlay was on top on the colorbox rendering unusable, as it would just close whenever I tried to focus an input. Any ideas how I can get round this?

Comment: My mistake.. you should also append the #cboxOverlay to the form:
$('#cboxOverlay, #colorbox').appendTo('form');

Comment: I just 2 days of my life to this.  Arrrrgggghh!  Thanks to everyone here for providing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used jQuery colorbox, but i had a similar problem with jQuery UI modal popup.  What it was doing was, when i attached the popup it moved the content div outside of the asp.net form so the controls were not getting posted back.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve it or find a work-around?  As mentioned in my post, if I use JavaScript to copy the field values to hidden form fields it will work, but since that's a hacked solution and I'm dealing with a password, my preference is not to do that.

Comment: I created a web service and used ajax to post the values and then updated the screen using javascript with the results of the web service call.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that worked for me in a particular .NET CMS (DNN) was to take Jack's fix and attach to the cbox_complete event.  Posting in case someone else might find this useful.

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function () {
    $("#colorbox, #cboxOverlay").appendTo('form:first');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem with colorbox & form, solved it this way. My problem was that the submit wasn't working since the fieldsets were stripped of the form tag; So if your form isn't posting in colorbox, try this, sending in the form id as the href for the colorbox content

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#login-trigger').click(function () {
            $.colorbox({
                inline: true,
                href: "#login-form",
                close: "×",
                onOpen: function () { $('#login-content').css({ display: 'block' }); },
                onClosed: function () { $('#login-content').css({ display: 'none' }); }
            });
            return false;
        });
```