# Button Click does not fire with fancybox2 from webForms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox-2

I have a custom control and it's been registered in main page in a hidden div. On page load I show a modal window (fancybox 2) with content the one that has the hidden div.

My problem is that this control has a button and it doesn't fire from the fancybox.

I tried this [Fancybox - ASP.NET button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686362/fancybox-asp-net-button-not-working#10753866) but nothing changed.

Does anyone know how to fix this? The preferable would be a fix without amending the fancybox.js.

**The code where the control is placed in**

```
<a href="#inline" style="display: none" id="trigerButton"></a>
<div id="inline" style="display: none; width: 500px;">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PhCtrl"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
```

**from codeBehind**

```
var ctrlName = LoadControl("~/Path/control.ascx");
ctrlName.ID="ctrlID";
PhCtrl.Controls.Add(ctrlName);
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("$(document).ready(function() {");
sb.Append("$('#trigerButton').fancybox({modal:true}).trigger('click');");
sb.Append("$('#clickNo').click(function(){$.fancybox.close(true)});");
sb.Append("});");
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(T), "_script", sb.ToString(), true);
```

**The custom control**

It has a button and this button doesn't fire

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Upgrade" OnClick="Button1_click" />
  protected void Button1_click(object s,EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something 
    }
```

I would appreciate any suggestions

Thanks

**SOLUTION**

I didn't manage to find a solution without editing the fancybox.js, though I replaced every

```
appendTo('body')
```

with

```
appendTo('form:first')
```

Comment: Is this WebForms, or MVC (I wonder because WebForms can play with control IDs). Also, could you show us the html, and code to fire the fancybox?

Comment: Stroumfie, do you get post back and the function is not fire or not post back at all ?

Comment: It doesn't fire at all. The same control works well if it's in not it the fancybox

Comment: @StrouMfios The main reason is because the funcy box is changing the DOM and this input button is place it somewhere in the page as doublicate control. I think that is probably even render it somewhere outside of the form. Can you please check this out with the inspection tools of the browser ? to see where the final render box is made ? in witch place ? is the final input control inside the form ?

Comment: It doesn't has a duplicate button but it's outside the form. So it can't be fired. I am looking to overide somehow the init method

Comment: @StrouMfios So I will make this as an answer because I find the issue.

Comment: You find the issue and thank you for this. I want to mark it as answer but since it is not the solution, I am afraid that will mislead people who will read this. Anyway, I will mark it and if I find the solution I will edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for this issues is because the funcybox is making modifications on the DOM struct in order to make the dialog and place it somewhere in the page.

In your case the issue can be that the end rendered control is place the final input button outside the asp.net form, and that's why is not even fired.

### Update

I found a similar question, on similar box. The solution may also work here

Its add the dialog creation inside the form using the

```
jQuery('#dialogof').appendTo('form');
```

[ASP.NET Form Fields Not POSTing from colorbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424638/asp-net-form-fields-not-posting-from-colorbox)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try This
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
     parent: "form:first", // jQuery selector
});
```