# Submit button not working in Colorbox modal window

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I have a submit button in a ColorBox modal window. If I click the button nothing happens.

If I move the button outside of the ColorBox window to the main page content it works fine.

The ColorBox brings up some hidden div content:

```
$.colorbox({
                inline: true,
                href: "#popup",
                width: "580px",
                height: "350px",
                top: "100px",

                opacity: 0.8,
                modal: true,
                scrolling: false,
                onCleanup: function () {
                    $("div#popup").hide();
                }
            });
```

The button is just a simple asp button:

```
<asp:Button ID="cashBtn" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click"  />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Managed to fix it using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424638/asp-net-form-fields-not-posting-from-colorbox

Answer (score 2):

Please check if your colorbox dialog is rendered inside your form tag.

You should append your dialog to the form tag.